# BEM and Overriding Bootstrap Styles

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bem

I just started looking at BEM about 30 minutes ago, and I have hit my first road block with it.

I am building a project with twitter bootstrap and I decided to use BEM architecture for my styles, I tried overriding bootstraps hover effect on a stacked list but this won't work.

```
<ul class="nav nav-stacked side-nav">
    <li class='side-nav__item'><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class='side-nav__item'><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Below is my Style

```
.side-nav {
   position: relative;
   &__item {
     a {
        &:hover {
          font-weight: bold;
          background: none;
        }
     }
  }
}
```

The hover effect won't go away unless I force it with `!important`, I honestly saw issues like this coming but decided to try it anyways.

I see the issue has to do with bootstraps specificity, as my style is rendered below bootstraps style for the hover effect.

Find a link to working issue: https://jsfiddle.net/3321L7xL/

Comment: @Shameen no actually, I am concatenating the parent name with the child name, so that rather than nesting it will have just a single element

Comment: your code is perfect and i have checked compiling here ... https://www.sassmeister.com/

Comment: inspect the element when hovered and check in browser console..

Comment: I am sorry, maybe the question was not clear enough @ChandraShekhar, I have updated it, the problem is overriding bootstraps style

Comment: The specificity of your selectors has to be equal to, or higher than, the specificity of the original selectors from bootstrap.

Comment: @James Okpe George, it is working fine here check this .......... https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/b1ev0w34/1/

Comment: check the order you are loading css files in your html document once.

Comment: @ChandraShekhar You made use of bootstrap version 4, try this https://jsfiddle.net/3321L7xL/

Comment: @chazsolo I know, but the way BEM is structured is to eliminate this specificity

Comment: Not sure what you mean by eliminating specificity - your selector, once it's processed, is `.side-nav__item a:hover`. That has a specificity of `0.0.0.2.1`. If that's higher than the specificity of the rules from bootstrap, then you should be good to go. If not, you need a more specific selector.

Comment: eg. change `&__item {` to `& > .side-nav__item {`

Comment: You are right @chazsolo I broke the rule on that one, the link is supposed to have a class of `side-nav__link`, Even after adding the style, it won't work

Answer (score 0):

The key to the issue is [specificity of your selectors](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/). Your current selector

```
.side-nav__item a:hover { ... }
```

has a specificity of `0.0.0.2.1`. This specificity must be the same, or higher than, the specificity of the selectors from bootstrap to override their rules. When the specificity of selectors is the same, then order takes precedence (where the last rule wins).

To address this: make your selectors more specific. There are many ways, but with your current markup here is one:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav nav-stacked side-nav">
  <li class='side-nav__item'><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li class='side-nav__item'><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS/LESS**

```
.side-nav {
  position: relative;

  .side-nav__item {
    a {
      &:hover {
        font-weight: bold;
        background: none;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This results in a selector of `.side-nav .side-nav__item a:hover` with a specificity of `0.0.0.3.1` which is higher than the rules you are trying to override.